# How to either open a HUGE HTML file or split it into manageable chunks?

Tags: c#, html

So, I made an application that cross examines information from a database, compares it to an excel sheet, and the end result is a HUGE html file. Previously I had each HTML file separated, however when I tried to print them all out (2 sided) it wouldn't print properly in a batch so I had to manually make it happen.

The HTML code looks like:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
....random form crap
</body>
</html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
.... etc
</body>
</html>
```

and there's thousands of these. I either need to: simply open this file (it's 84mb and crashed every browser I've tried this in) and print the entire thing. Or separate it out into smaller chunks around 5mb each so I can print them out that way.

I appreciate any advice you guys may have on how I can accomplish this!

Comment: So single file contains multiple `<html></html>`?

Comment: You can use some linux tools to do this. Or if you are a windows users, you may want to install cygwin and try to use them that way :)

Comment: @VenomFangs: this would be a dirty hack :)

Comment: @@sll, what can I say :) When u have to open a 84mb file, you have to do what you have to do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using some linux tools. E.g. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/split-a-text-file-in-half-or-any-percentage-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: This was perfect, I cut the filesize down by using split -l 31700 test.htm   -- Thank you!!

Comment: @kogh No problem :) Many programs don't know how to properly buffer large files and try to load them all into memory, which is where you see thing blow up. Glad to here it did what you needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is tagged C# I will make the assumption that you want to accomplish this on Windows.

If you're doing this once and want a pragmatic solution, install Cygwin and use `split -p "<html>"`.

If you need a repeatable solution in C# open the file and read it line by line, outputting each line to a new file (don't forget to add the CRLF characters!). Each time you encounter `<html>` close the file you're outputting to and open a new file in which you redirect your output to.

Comment: how'd ur response get above mine?